# How to append from one csv file to another?

Tags: python, csv

Tried different ways. The closest way that may fit my need is the following code:

```
   with open('list.csv', 'r') as reader, open('list-history.csv', 'a') as writer:
         for row in reader:
             writer.writerow(row)
```

I'm using 'a' and tried 'w' as well but no luck. 
The result is no output at all.
Any suggestion, please? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to merge these 2 csv files?

Comment: Is column name same in both the csv ?

Comment: That's not how you use the `csv` module to create a [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader). Same for a [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer). Also, `file` objects created with `open()` don't have a `writerow()` method.

Comment: No merging. Just appending. Yes, the files remain exactly the same on first copy. Then file1 only adds the extra to file2. I'm on the suggestions. I'll report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there should be a error with a stacktrace.

Here: `writer.writerow(row)`

Normally `open()` returns file object which doesn't have `.writerow()` method, normally, you should use `.write(buffer)` method.

Example

```
with open('list.csv', 'r') as reader, open('list-history.csv', 'a') as writer:
    for row in reader:
        writer.write(row)
```

For me it works well with test csv files. But it doesn't merge them, just appends content of one file to another one.

Answer (score 2):

If both the csv columns have same name. Python's `pandas` module can help.

Example Code snippet.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("csv2.csv")

df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
df1.to_csv("new.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: My only doubt with pandas is not pandas-specific but I fear that keeping adding modules to the code beyond csv module will add extra weight for only pne run of my program. Any thought on this opinion/point?

Comment: This also works for me but I will have to test if the load testing is much different with csv only. I'm on removing duplicates now. So maybe pandas is a greater choice than csv on that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Okay, I don't think this will slow down your performance, whereas the dataframe give you more functionality. You can load specific modules to speed up load.

```from pandas import read_csv```
Dataframe will help you perform the higher operation (whenever needed) so it's good to get comfortable.